# Run scripts on multiple SQL Server Express instances

Tags: sql-server

I am asking for a solution to execute custom SQL scripts on multiple SQL Server Express instances on schedule.

Solutions that I have seen like ApexSQL Propagate and Redgate SQL Multi Script do not have a scheduler and I have more than 170 instances to run periodic jobs on them.

Any advice on how to optimally execute scheduled scripts will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Any Windows server OS has a built-in scheduler that you could easily use for this ....

Comment: @marc_s, I would like to make it centralized and there are often problems with OS scheduler and in my environment instances do not always reside on the same machines, they come back and forth, that is why I do not want to use Windows Scheduler, even though at the moment I am using it. It takes a lot of tiime to maintain such a system

Comment: I can think of lots of solutions, but none would be appropriate as an answer on SO. This is better suited for ServerFault or dba.SE.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I have posted my question here
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174805/run-scripts-on-multiple-sql-server-express-instances
So please feel free to share what solutions you can think of.

Comment: @GeorgeK: please do not cross post. One question, one site. You can delete the question here.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, well I would like more experienced people to see my question . I can delete it here , but SO is more popular than SE, so I will less likely get ideas on where to move

Comment: You can use SQL Server Agent as an Master Server and enlist all others as target for that job.

Comment: @GeorgeK: I understand why a cross-post is useful for *you*, but it's [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/). At least not without making the question *specific to the site you're posting it to*. As it is, this is not a good question for SO.

Comment: @DeanSavović, it is SQL Server Express without agent on all those 170 servers so it is not posiible to create a Master Server

Comment: @GeorgeK you can use Mgmt Studio functionality of registered servers. You have to register all 170 servers and then you can run a query against all of them. Or, if that is not a good solution for you you will have to write windows service...